# Does it hold that $\tan(A + B) = \frac{\tan(B) + \tan(A)}{\tan(A)\tan(B)+1}$?

Tags: geometry

I'm working through a bigger proof but have hit a roadblock and was I was hoping to use the trig identity for $\tan(A + B)$ but the expression I get doesn't seem to fit.

Is $\frac{\tan(B) + \tan(A)}{\tan(A)\tan(B)+1}$ the same as the identity for $\tan(A+B)$?

Comment: They are not the same.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting, but the denominator should be $1-\tan A\tan B$, not plus.

Answer (score 4):

No, the proposed identity is not valid. Instead, one has that
\begin{align*}
\tan(A + B) & = \frac{\sin(A + B)}{\cos(A + B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\sin(A)\cos(B) + \sin(B)\cos(A)}{\cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)}\\\\
& = \frac{\tan(A) + \tan(B)}{1 - \tan(A)\tan(B)}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it looks like you've confirmed they are not the same thing. I was wondering if my algebra skill were just not up to changing the original to the correct identity for tan(A+B)

Comment: @AP You are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

No.
$$
\tan(10^\circ+20^\circ)=\tan30\approx0.51\\
\neq(\tan 10^\circ+\tan 20^\circ)/(1+\tan10^\circ\tan20^\circ)\approx0.60
$$